# mysql find number of inner join whiteout relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

How con i find how many rows don't have an inner join relationship?

```
TABLE A
id | name | idpoints

TABLE B
id | point
```

any record on table A should have a relative record on table B
how can i find how many records on able A don't have a record on table B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `left join` to join the tables and then take all records where the `id` in tableB is `null`

```
select count(*) from tableA left join tableB on idpoints = tableB.id where tableB.id is null
```

Comment: @al404IT Yes of course. Sorry for that mistake. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM   TABLE_A A
  LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B
  ON B.ID = A.IDPOINTS
  WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```